# Characterization of bounded linear functional on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be a linear functional on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $f=\alpha\cdot\text{tr}$, where $\alpha$ is some complex number and $\text{tr}$ denotes the trace,
2. $f(AB-BA)=0$ for all $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$,
3. $f(XAX^{-1})=f(A)$, for all $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $X$ invertible in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$,
4. $|f(X)|\leq C\rho(X)$, where $C$ is some positive constant and where $\rho$ denotes the spectral radius.

I have proved the first two implication.

$1\implies 2:$ Assume that $f=\alpha\cdot\text{tr}$. Then for any $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, $$f(AB-BA)=\alpha\cdot\text{tr}(AB-BA)=0.$$
$2\implies 3:$ Assume that $f(AB-BA)=0$ for all $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then for any $A,B\in M_n$, we have $f(AB)=f(BA)$. Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $X$ is an invertible matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then $$f(XAX^{-1})=f(X^{-1}XA)=f(A).$$

Can anyone help me to prove the third and forth implications. Any help or advice is welcome.

Comment: Surely it is easier to prove (3) implies (1) first, then do the equivalence of (4) and ((1), (2) or (3)).  It is less slick, but more intuitive.

Comment: Thank you. I will try using your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3\implies 4:$ Let $J=D+N$ be the Jordan form of $X$, where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ is nilpotent. Then $N$ is similar to $2N$ and $f(N)=f(2N)$. It follows from the linearity of $f$ that $f(N)=0$. Now let $P$ be the permutation matrix for a cyclic shift. Then
$$
f(D)
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(D)
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(P^kDP^{-k})
=\frac{1}{n}f\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}P^kDP^{-k}\right)
=\frac{1}{n}f\big(\operatorname{tr}(D)I\big)
=\frac{f(I)}{n}\operatorname{tr}(D).
$$
Therefore $|f(X)|=|f(J)|=|f(D)+f(N)|=|\frac{f(I)}{n}\operatorname{tr}(D)|\le|f(I)|\rho(D)=|f(I)|\rho(X)$.

$4\implies 1:$ Define
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&1\\ -1&-1\\ \hline&&0_{(n-2)\times(n-2)}\end{array}\right]
\quad\text{and}\quad
B=\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}0&1\\ 0&0\\ \hline&&0_{(n-2)\times(n-2)}\end{array}\right].
$$
Note that the subspace of all traceless matrices is spanned by matrices of the forms $PAP^T$ and $PBP^T$, where $P$ denotes a permutation matrix. Since $A$ and $B$ are nilpotent, every traceless matrix is a sum of nilpotent matrices. However, for any nilpotent matrix $N$, we have $f(N)=0$ because $|f(N)|\le C\rho(N)=0$. Therefore, by the linearity of $f$, we have $f(Z)=0$ for every traceless matrix $Z$. In particular, if we put $Z=X-\frac{\operatorname{tr}(X)}{n}I$, we obtain
$$
f(X)
=f\left(\frac{\operatorname{tr}(X)}{n}I\right)
=\frac{f(I)}{n}\operatorname{tr}(X).
$$

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your help. I have a little doubt. Can you help me justify why every traceless matrix is a sum of nilpotent matrices?

Comment: @user_jr Because the subspace of all traceless matrices is spanned by nilpotent matrices.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get it.